# Wire size for 125ft

Tags: wiring

I have a hot water heater.  Its 30gal tank. 125ft away from my breaker box. will a 20amp breaker with 12-2 wire still good for that distance

Comment: what is the current requirement of the heater?

Comment: What the heck sort of water heater uses a 20A circuit?

Comment: http://waterheatertimer.org/Figure-Volts-Amps-Watts-for-water-heater.html

Comment: http://waterheatertimer.org/Color-codewire.html

Comment: Hot water heater? As an old plumber once told me "If the water is hot why are you heating it?" Other than that you really need to post the wattage of the heater.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, you'll need 10-2 on a 30A breaker, owing to the 23A of current typical in 30gal water heaters.   However voltage drop will be reasonable.

Comment: One rule of thumb I have heard and follow is for every 100' of circuit length, up the wire size one gauge.  This keeps the voltage drop under 5%.  The breaker will remain at 30-Amps.

Comment: @PaulLogan I would make it more like 150-200', and I would base it on your practical everyday loading, certainly not the breaker provisioning. I did run the numbers on Southwire's calc and they were at around 2.5% at 23A which is fine.